# Navigating conditions in visual studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Say I have a giant "If" condition that is several hundred (or thousand) lines long, with another "If" nested inside that like so:
(Example in VB.Net)

```
if (something) then
<lots of lines of code>
    if (something else) then
       <lots more code>
           <X>
    end if
end if
```

So, i have two If conditions, and nested in the inner "if" is point "X".
Does anyone know of a hotkey or something that allows me to jump from point "X" up the hierarchy of conditions so that it snaps onto the "if" statements (in this example "If", but I suppose it could be "for","while", "Do until" etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, but if the method is too big to be able to see this sort of stuff manually, it sounds like you may need some refactoring and splitting things out into different methods...

Comment: That's literally what I'm in the process of doing, hence why the thing I'm looking for would be helpful! :)

Comment: Haha!  Fair enough :)

Comment: Just for understanding, is point "X" identical in each instance?

Comment: Point X is just representative of a block of code that is nested in potentially several "If" statements, all i want is some kind of hotkey (like Crtl + up arrow or something) that will snap to the surrounding "if", or "Do while" or whatever.